# scala gather a list of pair combination

Tags: scala, functional-programming

given the following:

```
Map( X -> List( (Option[Ob1], Option[ObjA]), (Option[Obj1], Option[ObjB]), (Option[Obj2], Option[ObjA]), (Option[Obj2], Option[ObjB]), (..., ...) ))
```

I need to collect and group the combinations into a pair of 2 lists (while keeping the map and key portion the same for now):

```
Map (X -> ( List(Obj1, Obj2, Obj3 ...), List(ObjA, ObjB ...) )
```

So in other words, I need to perform sort of the opposite operation of creating all the combinations of 2 lists and I need the "original" 2 lists containing each unique element. I have tried various combinations of unzip and mapping but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to do something like this to the `Map`:

```
.mapValues(_.unzip).mapValues{ case (a, b) => (a.distinct, b.distinct) }
```

If you need sorting, you can just chain that against the `distinct` methods.

Comment: My fault, but I forgot to mention that in the original List, each Obj is actually wrapped in an Option. I am getting an error on the unzip operation saying "No implicit view available from anorm" on the Option pair.  I'm not sure if the 2 are related.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the Option.  sorry about that

Comment: @oym The only difference would be `b.flatten.distinct` instead.

Comment: I see.  The strange thing is that when I decompose your solution and run it incrementally, I can't get passed the .mapValues(_.unzip) part without getting the error I mentioned above. If it helps, the exact type (from Intellij) I have prior to any transformation is: Map[X, List[~[Option[Y], Option[Z]]]]

Comment: @oym ~[A, B] is an Anorm case class, and not a tuple, so that's why. You need to map the Anorm row parsers to tuples if you want to make that work.

Comment: oh I see. ok, thanks. I'll accept your answer as is since my premise was far off.

Comment: I ought to write a blog post about dealing with those many-to-one relations in Anorm. They can get pretty complicated.

Comment: I'm biased of course. but that would be fantastic! I thought I had it handled from your help on the other post, but then I had to introduce a second many-to-one into the query, hence this question